# Removing value from local Dictionary when firebase child deleted swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I am learning on how to properly use firebase realtime database. I am building an app where user can change their work locations (base). in my profile settings controller user choose their base via a pickerView. The real time database gets updated properly. I have the list of all users and seperate list per base . Where is get stuck is on the main view controller.
I have collection view that display a list of user of my own location.
My goal is to see who comes to my location or depart my location.
I have 2 functions one that fetch my own user datas . which determine the current base i want to dispaly

```
func fetchCurrentUser() {

        if currentUser == nil {
            common.errorAlert("Could not retrieve user details.")
            return
        }

        guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

        ref.child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
            if !snapshot.exists() { return }
            let userDetailsData = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            self.id = userDetailsData?["id"] as? String ?? ""
            self.myBase = userDetailsData?["base"] as? String ?? ""
            self.indexBasePicker = userDetailsData?["baseIndex"] as? Int ?? 0
            self.headerPosition(self.indexBasePicker)
            if self.myBase != "" {
                self.fetchAllUsers()
            }
        }
    }
```

The second fetchallusers at my location:

```
func fetchAllUsers() {

        ref.child(myBase).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let user = User(dictionary: dictionary)
                if  user.isAdmin == true {
                    self.usersArray.append(user)
                    self.reloadTeamCollectionView()
                }
            }
        })

        ref.child(myBase).observe(.childRemoved, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let user = User(dictionary: dictionary)

                for (index, userArray) in self.usersArray.enumerated() {
                    if userArray.id == user.id {
                        print(index)
                        self.usersArray.remove(at: index)
                        self.reloadTeamCollectionView()
                    }
                }
            }
        })

    }
```

the problem is when someone join my current location it gets added to the list , sometimes severaltimes. and when someone departs some time the app crashes with index out of range error

any help would be tremendously appreciated

```
.
  "users" : {
    "BdxqjmhjM0O3nV8uK9iC3HICHy32" : {
      "availableStatus" : false,
      "base" : "FRA",
      "baseIndex" : 4,
      "committee" : "★",
      "email" : "",
      "fBMessenger" : "",
      "fileNumber" : "",
      "iMessage" : "",
      "id" : "BdxqjmhjM0O3nV8uK9iC3HICHy32",
      "isAdmin" : true,
      "isOnline" : true,
      "name" : "",
      "phone" : "",
      "position" : "",
      "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myunion-16f31.appspot.com/o/BdxqjmhjM0O3nV8uK9iC3HICHy32%2Fprofile_images%2FprofilePhoto?alt=media&token=e898f36f-7c3a-42a3-be4b-0a1b74cbd224",
      "whatsapp" : ""
    },
    "DKfHhnwMgbOfGg3IpqG9QxlayxV2" : {
      "availableStatus" : false,
      "base" : "FRA",
      "baseIndex" : 4,
      "committee" : "★ Officers",
      "email" : "",
      "fBMessenger" : "",
      "fileNumber" : "",
      "iMessage" : "",
      "id" : "DKfHhnwMgbOfGg3IpqG9QxlayxV2",
      "isAdmin" : true,
      "isOnline" : false,
      "name" : "",
      "phone" : "",
      "position" : "",
      "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myunion-16f31.appspot.com/o/DKfHhnwMgbOfGg3IpqG9QxlayxV2%2Fprofile_images%2FprofilePhoto?alt=media&token=204f4187-b508-405e-9835-bfdf5250019f",
      "whatsapp" : ""
    },
    "GMupdPogn7YUag855TnWJkuzVzo1" : {
      "availableStatus" : "Online",
      "base" : "FRA",
      "baseIndex" : 4,
      "committee" : "Eap",
      "email" : "lisa@lisa.com",
      "fBMessenger" : "",
      "fileNumber" : "u182874",
      "iMessage" : "",
      "id" : "GMupdPogn7YUag855TnWJkuzVzo1",
      "isAdmin" : true,
      "name" : "",
      "phone" : "",
      "position" : "",
      "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myunion-16f31.appspot.com/o/GMupdPogn7YUag855TnWJkuzVzo1%2Fprofile_images%2FprofilePhoto?alt=media&token=8b3ec821-adad-47a9-943f-2cd4af50e436",
      "whatsapp" : ""
    },
    "LS8plMZmlmSXsu9kVZxXRKsuPT13" : {
      "availableStatus" : true,
      "base" : "FRA",
      "baseIndex" : 4,
      "committee" : "Communication",
      "email" : ",
      "fBMessenger" : "",
      "fileNumber" : "",
      "iMessage" : "",
      "id" : "LS8plMZmlmSXsu9kVZxXRKsuPT13",
      "isAdmin" : true,
      "isOnline" : true,
      "name" : "",
      "phone" : "",
      "position" : "Chair",
      "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myunion-16f31.appspot.com/o/LS8plMZmlmSXsu9kVZxXRKsuPT13%2Fprofile_images%2FprofilePhoto?alt=media&token=10ec728b-db42-485a-849d-0e2bcc0b3ba3",
      "whatsapp" : "+33642056110"
    },
    "sqfl1FmeiiOuoq8dPePULYDEsnv2" : {
      "availableStatus" : true,
      "base" : "FRA",
      "baseIndex" : 4,
      "committee" : "",
      "email" : "nonadmin@test.com",
      "fBMessenger" : "",
      "fileNumber" : "u182222",
      "iMessage" : "",
      "id" : "sqfl1FmeiiOuoq8dPePULYDEsnv2",
      "isAdmin" : false,
      "isOnline" : false,
      "name" : "Nonadmin Test",
      "phone" : "",
      "position" : "",
      "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myunion-16f31.appspot.com/o/sqfl1FmeiiOuoq8dPePULYDEsnv2%2Fprofile_images%2FprofilePhoto?alt=media&token=d4cfa840-954e-41fa-8490-23a5cd49fa56",
      "whatsapp" : ""
    }
  },
  "usersOffline" : {
    "DKfHhnwMgbOfGg3IpqG9QxlayxV2" : {
      "base" : "FRA",
      "baseIndex" : 4,
      "committee" : "★ Officers",
      "email" : "merv",
      "fBMessenger" : "",
      "fileNumber" : "",
      "iMessage" : "",
      "id" : "",
      "isAdmin" : true,
      "isOnline" : false,
      "name" : "Merv",
      "phone" : "",
      "position" : "Vice President",
      "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myunion-16f31.appspot.com/o/DKfHhnwMgbOfGg3IpqG9QxlayxV2%2Fprofile_images%2FprofilePhoto?alt=media&token=204f4187-b508-405e-9835-bfdf5250019f",
      "whatsapp" : ""
    },
    "sqfl1FmeiiOuoq8dPePULYDEsnv2" : {
      "base" : "FRA",
      "baseIndex" : 4,
      "committee" : "",
      "email" : "nonadmin@test.com",
      "fBMessenger" : "",
      "fileNumber" : "u182222",
      "iMessage" : "",
      "id" : "sqfl1FmeiiOuoq8dPePULYDEsnv2",
      "isAdmin" : false,
      "isOnline" : false,
      "name" : "Nonadmin Test",
      "phone" : "",
      "position" : "",
      "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myunion-16f31.appspot.com/o/sqfl1FmeiiOuoq8dPePULYDEsnv2%2Fprofile_images%2FprofilePhoto?alt=media&token=d4cfa840-954e-41fa-8490-23a5cd49fa56",
      "whatsapp" : ""
    }
  },
  "usersOnline" : {
    "BdxqjmhjM0O3nV8uK9iC3HICHy32" : {
      "base" : "FRA",
      "baseIndex" : 4,
      "committee" : "★ Officers",
      "email" : "",
      "fBMessenger" : "",
      "fileNumber" : "",
      "iMessage" : "",
      "id" : "",
      "isAdmin" : true,
      "isOnline" : true,
      "name" : "",
      "phone" : "",
      "position" : "",
      "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myunion-16f31.appspot.com/o/BdxqjmhjM0O3nV8uK9iC3HICHy32%2Fprofile_images%2FprofilePhoto?alt=media&token=e898f36f-7c3a-42a3-be4b-0a1b74cbd224",
      "whatsapp" : "+31620422185"
    },
    "LS8plMZmlmSXsu9kVZxXRKsuPT13" : {
      "base" : "FRA",
      "baseIndex" : 4,
      "committee" : "Communication",
      "email" : "",
      "fBMessenger" : "",
      "fileNumber" : "",
      "iMessage" : "",
      "id" : "LS8plMZmlmSXsu9kVZxXRKsuPT13",
      "isAdmin" : true,
      "isOnline" : true,
      "name" : "",
      "phone" : "",
      "position" : "Chair",
      "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myunion-16f31.appspot.com/o/LS8plMZmlmSXsu9kVZxXRKsuPT13%2Fprofile_images%2FprofilePhoto?alt=media&token=10ec728b-db42-485a-849d-0e2bcc0b3ba3",
      "whatsapp" : "+33642056110"
    }
  }
}
```

i have 2 references

```
  let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users")
    let refOnline = Database.database().reference(withPath: "usersOnline")
    let refOffline = Database.database().reference(withPath: "usersOffline")
```

this is how the user profile gets updated whe the save button is pressed

```
   func updateDatasIsOnline(online: Bool) {

           if currentUser == nil {
         //      common.errorAlert("Error could not read user details")
               print("Error could not read user details")
               return
           }


           let filename = "profilePhoto"


           Storage.storage().reference().child(self.currentUser?.uid ?? "").child("profile_images").child(filename).downloadURL { (url, error) in
               guard let downloadURL = url else {
                   common.errorAlert(error?.legibleLocalizedDescription ?? "")
                   return }

               let userValues = [
                   "id": self.currentUser?.uid ?? "",
                   "name": self.nameTextField.text ?? "",
                   "committee": self.selectedCommitteeName,
                   "position": self.positionTextField.text ?? "",
                   "base": self.myBase,
                   "baseIndex": self.basePickerPosition,
                   "isAdmin": self.isAdmin,
                   "isOnline": online,
                   "email": self.emailTextField.text ?? "",
                   "phone": self.reformatPhoneNumberForDataBase(self.phoneNumberTextField.text ?? ""),
                   "iMessage": self.iMessageTextField.text ?? "",
                   "whatsapp": self.reformatPhoneNumberForDataBase(self.whatsappTextField.text ?? ""),
                   "fBMessenger": self.fBMessengerTextField.text ?? "",
                   "profileImageUrl": downloadURL.absoluteString,
                   "fileNumber": self.fileNbr
                   ] as [String : Any]

            if online == true {
                 self.ref.child(self.currentUser?.uid ?? "").updateChildValues(["isOnline" : true])
                self.refOnline.child(self.currentUser?.uid ?? "").setValue(userValues)
                self.refOffline.child(self.currentUser?.uid ?? "").removeValue()
            } else {
                self.ref.child(self.currentUser?.uid ?? "").updateChildValues(["isOnline" : false])
                self.refOffline.child(self.currentUser?.uid ?? "").setValue(userValues)
                self.refOnline.child(self.currentUser?.uid ?? "").removeValue()
            }
        }

       }
```

Comment: Can you put break points in the removal and check if the index it is trying to remove is a valid index Eg: [1,2] -> Index: 2

Comment: Also I'm assuming that the Index Out of Ranges comes from usersArray right?

Comment: yes it does gives me an out of range on the .childRemoved observer self.userArray.remove(at: index)         Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: There's not a whole lot wrong with your code so good job. A few things could be fixed but it would help to know what your Firebase structure looks like. For example, what's stored in *ref/myBase/*? Also, if a user moves from one base to another are you deleting the node from one node and re-writing it to a different node? Have you considered a child node called `base_location` that you can simply update when they move bases? To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure.

Comment: here is the database structure. i have changed a few things after looking around. I created 2 sections online users and off line users. same collectionView 2 sections . online users section 0 and offline users section 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems line you are moving a lot of data around within the database. That can get expensive but also consumes a lot of bandwidth. In other words, with the current code, if a users status changes from online to offline, your code is currently removing all of the user data from one node and re-writing it to another when all that's really needed is to toggle an online flag from yes to no.

I present another option that may help in the long run and while it's not troubleshooting your existing code, it may be a better option.

The idea here is to keep the user data in one place and simply change the child nodes to reflect a different status; a different base, online/offline etc.

To do that, that if a property (child node) falls within the criteria of a query, you'll be notified. If it falls out of the criteria you'll be notified.

Here's what a proposed user node would look like. Note there are no offline or online nodes, just the users node

```
users
   uid_0 //a users uid
      base: "FRA"
      name: "Frank"
      online: "no"
   uid_1
      base: "ENG"
      name: "Henry"
      online: "yes"
   uid_0 
      base: "FRA"
      name: "Leroy"
      online: "yes"
```

From this you know that Frank is stationed in France but not online, Henry is in England and online and Leroy is also in France and online.

Here's my users class and an array to store them in

```
class UserAndBaseClass {
    var uid = ""
    var name = ""
    var base = ""
    var online = ""

    init(withSnap: DataSnapshot) {
        self.uid = withSnap.key
        self.name = withSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as? String ?? "No Name"
        self.base = withSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "base").value as? String ?? "No Base"
        self.online = withSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "online").value as? String ?? "Offline"
    }
}

var usersArray = [UserAndBaseClass]()
```

In the first section of code, addedQuery, queries all of the users that belong to the current users base, FRA and stores them in an array. This leaves an observer on the users node so if any users base becomes FRA, it will then fall within that query's parameters and is *added* to the query. (hence firing the .childAdded event)

The second section, removedQuery, establishes a query on all users that match the query and the event is fired if the base becomes something other than FRA - e.g. the child is *removed* from the query parameters and the .childRemoved event fires.

Note we are not using .childChanged at all since the first two queries cover  it.

```
func observeUserBases() {

    let currentUserBase = "FRA"

    //get everyone in the current users base, FRA. This also fires if a user changes to this base
    let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")
    let addedQuery = usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "base").queryEqual(toValue: currentUserBase)
    addedQuery.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        let user = UserAndBaseClass(withSnap: snapshot)
        self.usersArray.append(user)
        print("\(user.name) has been added to your base")
    })

    //this will catch any users that were removed as well as users who left your base
    let removedQuery = usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "base").queryEqual(toValue: "FRA")
    removedQuery.observe(.childRemoved, with: { snapshot in
        let keyToRemove = snapshot.key
        if let index = self.usersArray.firstIndex(where: { $0.uid == keyToRemove } ) {
            let name = self.usersArray[index].name
            print("\(name) has left your base")
            self.usersArray.remove(at: index)
        }
    })


    let onlineQuery = usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "online").queryEqual(toValue: "yes")
    onlineQuery.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        let keyOfChanged = snapshot.key
        let base = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "base").value as? String ?? "No Base"

        if base == currentUserBase {
            if let index = self.usersArray.firstIndex(where: { $0.uid == keyOfChanged } ) {
                let name = self.usersArray[index].name
                print("\(name) is now online")
                self.usersArray[index].online = "yes"
            }
        }
    })

    let offlineQuery = usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "online").queryEqual(toValue: "no")
    offlineQuery.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        let keyOfChanged = snapshot.key
        let base = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "base").value as? String ?? "No Base"

        if base == currentUserBase {
            if let index = self.usersArray.firstIndex(where: { $0.uid == keyOfChanged } ) {
                let name = self.usersArray[index].name
                print("\(name) has gone offline")
                self.usersArray[index].online = "no"
            }
        }
    })
}
```

The last two sections, online and offline query, are structured a little different; each is looking for nodes that match the query parameters. One is looking for nodes that match online = yes, the offline one matches nodes that match offline = no. Noting that the code is actually watching ALL users but ignoring users that are not in the current users base.

An alternative to this is to add individual observers to each users/online node that's part of this base. You would do that in the addedQuery closure and add an observer to each users node as it's added, and then in the removeQuery, remove the observer as the user leaves the base. I will leave that to an exercise.

Hope this helps by presenting an alternative to moving all of that data around.

Comment: DAMN! i implemented it and it work quiet well . i wish i could shake your hand and buy you a beer.    the only thing is that sometimes i have the same people several time in my collection view.... while the console shows only one name on or off line... possibly its where i place collection view reload...    also when i press save profile... where you could change your base... i post a notification for an observer to change the main view controller to fetch my datas again with the new base pointing to your function  observeUserBases()

Comment: perfect thank you... let me see how i can accept this to help others . again than you